# Is there any drawback if i use special charterers such as - or ( ) inside my wiki pages URL

Tags: 2013, search, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki, information-architecture

I am starting a new Enterprise wiki site collection inside my sharepoint enterprise server 2013, and currently i am building a document which will define the procedure for creating new wiki pages by our end users. so i define the following format for the wiki pages name/url:-

```
1. "Page Topic" - "Customer Name" ("Type").aspx
```

so the wiki pages urls will look something as follow:-

1. `Telephone List - CustomerA (Information).aspx`
2. `Setup a new PC - CustomerB (Technical).aspx`

now sharepoint will allow me to define these characters without any problem. but since i will inform our end users to follow this naming standards when creating new wiki pages, so i want to know if using special characters such as `-` & `(` & `)` is a valid appraoch or it will create some problems?, mainly inside these areas :-

1. Search & search results
2. when building links between wiki pages?

Can anyone adivce on this please?

Comment: `-` in search (KQL) means `NOT` , so if you would search for `-CustomerA` you would get the results that don't contain `CustomerA`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx)

Comment: @GintasK but i can in this case wrap the search by "-CustomerA" is this correct ?

Comment: I think so. The brackets `()` are also used in KQL, but the syntax is very specific, so it shouldn't cause any problems. Atleast for the examples provided. Building links between wiki pages should also work fine as if it wouldn't, Microsoft wouldn't allow those characters.